# How to parse this nested List json that has no keys on inner list objects?

Tags: android, json

I'm using an price API that returns a nested list

```
{"prices":[
    [1676505600000,24307.875101631602],
    [1676592000000,23756.907281577434]
  ],
"market_caps":[
   [1676505600000,468820317786.9533],
   [1676592000000,459293697174.9459],
   [1676678400000,475194230168.09973]
  ]
}
```

I can't figure out how to structure my Java Object so it's successfully parsed.

I've tried

```
public class QueryResult {
    @SerializedName("prices")
    List<List<Prices>> listPrices;

    public List<List<Prices>> getListPrices() {
        return listPrices;
    }
}
```

```
public class Prices {
    private long timestamp;
    private double price;

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

I still get the error

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Usually the items in the nested list would have a key, but in this case it doesn't.

So I'm not quite sure  how to do it here.

**Edit:________________________________________________________**

I'm already using Gson with retrofit

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    public Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Still can't get it to work. Not sure why

Comment: What library are you using to parse json? There might be a way to add a custom deserialiser to it

Comment: I'm using Retrofit with a GsonConverterFactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a lack of understanding of how the Gson library and Json format work. What you want to achieve in your question is not possible the way you want to do it. There is a way to do it, though, and it differs a bit from what you might expect.

```
{"prices":[
    [1676505600000,24307.875101631602],
    [1676592000000,23756.907281577434]
  ],
"market_caps":[
   [1676505600000,468820317786.9533],
   [1676592000000,459293697174.9459],
   [1676678400000,475194230168.09973]
  ]
}
```

Here both `prices` and `market_caps` are two-dimensional `double` arrays - basically, matrices - meaning they do not contain Prices objects as you expect them, but an array(or as you parse them a List) of `double`s with the `innerList[0]` element being timestamp and `innerList[1]` being price.

In order to parse them correctly your model should look like this:

```
public class QueryResult {
    List<List<double>> prices;
}
```

And if you want to have them as objects the simple approach will require having this getter for it:

```
public List<Price> getListOfPrices() {
        List<Price> result = new ArrayList<Prices>();
        for (List<double> innerList: prices){
           result.add(Price(innerList.get(0), innerList.get(1)));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The method above will calculate every time it is called; thus, you would want to store it somewhere.

And if you want to utilize a converter, as @Sudhakar suggested in the answer above, which is more correct but also a bit more complicated. It is called [@JsonAdapter in the context of the Gson library](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) or [GsonConverterFactory in the context of Retrofit 2.0 library](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/retrofit-2-define-custom-gson-converter-factory).

I don't think it is needed, though, in your case, since the easier method is reasonably sufficient if handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Need to use Gson Converter**

```
  public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"prices\":[[1676505600000,24307.875101631602],[1676592000000,23756.907281577434]],\"market_caps\":[[1676505600000,468820317786.9533],[1676592000000,459293697174.9459],[1676678400000,475194230168.09973]]}";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Data data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);

        List<List<Double>> prices = data.prices;
        List<List<Double>> marketCaps = data.market_caps;

        System.out.println(prices);
        System.out.println(marketCaps);
    }

    private static class Data {
        private List<List<Double>> prices;
        private List<List<Double>> market_caps;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm already using a Gson converter. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Check my edit above.

Comment: List<Double> will contain both timestamp and price. 0 index contains timestamp and 1 index contains price 
'private List<List<Double>> prices;
for(price : prices){
double timestamp = price.get(0)
double price = price.get(1)
}'